# Can't Step Into Android's Java Code

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio

I'm trying to debug a problem with EditText (an entry in my form is mysteriously getting set back to blank). I tried to place a breakpoint on EditText's setText and getText methods: the latter because I know it must get called. But the breakpoints are not on valid, executable code.

When I step into the methods from my code (F7) it steps through comments and un-related code.

The debugger isn't working with the same "source." Is there anything I can do to correct this?

P.S. I considered extending EditText and overriding only setText() so that I could at least trap the culprit, but EditText has no default constructor and I would have to replicate more and more of the base EditText class.

Comment: Can you post the code that is misbehaving?

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding.

Comment: post the code which is causing the error.

Comment: A clean and rebuild fixed it (close enough). The setter is only two lines (calls up to super) but I could only set a breakpoint on the method entry. That gave me the usual warning about performance, but worked.

I didn't think I need to post the code here. It's Java's own code. and the problem was not with a specific line of code.